# Alternative for Google Pronunciation service (sounds like)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

Currently, I'm researching NLP systems and Machine Learning.

I was wondering if there was an open source library like Google Pronunciation or if I could create my own program.

In essence, Google offers a service that you can use to look up a word's pronunciation and Google will display a guide like "uh·kaam·pluhsh for accomplish" the libraries that I found only offer phonetic format such as "AAH0 K AA1 M P L IH0 SH" or its IPA of /əˈkʌm.plɪʃ/

My goal is to create a piece of code that takes "accomplish" as input and returns "uh·kaam·pluhsh".

[image: google service]